# Solve an equation with trial and error in matlab

Tags: matlab, iteration, trial

I have a 1024X1 double "w_e" and I wish to use it to find "w" which satisfies the following equation:
w_e-w=-0.7584*w^2 in matlab.
Ive tried :

```
for i=0.001:0.0001:10
    a(i)=w_e-w(i);
    b(i)=-0.7584*w^2;
end

a=b;
```

Can anyone please help me.  Thanks

Comment: you cannot index a variable `w` with non-integer values. What should the code represent at all?

Comment: your question is unclear. What is the equation you want to solve?

Comment: I would like to solve for w given the equation w_e-w = -0.7584*w^2.  it is obviously a quadratic, but I have an array of values w_e (these are a range of real frequencies that must be ordered in a spectrum by the way).  I want to obtain a set of w's such that the equation is satisfied.  The way I want it done is from a list of frequency unknown frequencies w, which of these will hold to satisfy the equation.